# Handle mouse event anywhere with JavaFX

Tags: java, event-handling, javafx, mouseevent

I have a JavaFX application, and I would like to add an event handler for a mouse click anywhere within the scene. The following approach works ok, but not exactly in the way I want to. Here is a sample to illustrate the problem:

```java
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    root = new AnchorPane();
    scene = new Scene(root,500,200);
    scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("mouse click detected! "+event.getSource());
        }
    });

    Button button = new Button("click here");
    root.getChildren().add(button);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

If I click anywhere in empty space, the `EventHandler` invokes the `handle()` method, but if i click the `button`, the `handle()` method is not invoked. There are many buttons and other interactive elements in my application, so I need an approach to catch clicks on those elements as well without having to manually add a new handler for every single element.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can add an event filter to the scene with [addEventFilter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addEventFilter%28javafx.event.EventType,%20javafx.event.EventHandler%29).  This will be called before the event is consumed by any child controls.  Here's what the code for the event filter looks like.

```
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println("mouse click detected! " + mouseEvent.getSource());
    }
});
```