JavaFX Application Wide Mouse Event Listener?
I'm trying to find a way to listen to all mouse events for a JavaFX application. Not just events on a particular stage, scene or node but the whole application. Does anyone know of a solution?

Doesn't the Stage cover the whole application?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597939/handle-mouse-event-anywhere-with-javafx

SedJ601 - Not from what I've found. A JavaFX Application is passed the primary stage, but afterwards you can create as many stages as you like for dialogs, etc. The link you point refers to a specific Scene.

Anytime you create a new Scene, go ahead and add the appropriate listens or filter to the Scene.

"Anytime you create a new Scene, go ahead and add the appropriate listens or filter to the Scene." --> A real application can have hundreds/thousands of Scenes !! Do you seriously believe this is a valid solution?

@GrahamSeed An application cannot realistically have that many Scene instances, unless you are doing things wrong. Make sure you replace the root of an existing scene whenever possible, and only create new scene instances when you really need to. Use a factory pattern of some kind to create the scenes when you do need them. That way you have a single place in your code to attach any event handlers you need every time. (You can do the same for stylesheets.)

You can observe the window list and:

Filter window mouse events

OR

Monitor the window scene property and filter scene mouse events.

Alternately, as noted by James in comments:

Use a factory pattern of some kind to create the scenes when you do need them. That way you have a single place in your code to attach any event handlers you need every time. (You can do the same for stylesheets.)

Sometimes JavaFX will create new popup windows for popup controls like ColorPicker or context menus.  I think monitoring the window list and adding appropriate filters based on that will allow you to filter mouse events for those overlay windows, but I'm not sure if adding event handlers at creation time for your scenes will allow that.

Adding mouse event filters to scenes is described in:

Handle mouse event anywhere with JavaFX

A filter with MouseEvent.ANY will catch any kind of mouse event.

jewelsea - Thanks, the Window list was exactly what I was looking for.  I've added a change listener to the list and then added add/remove event listeners to each scene.
